# import all functions in a package to one module of the same package

Tags: python, import, module

I have a package `animals` with several thousand modules `dog_1.py`, `cat_3.py`, etc.  Each module contains functions `color()`, `size()`, etc, and these functions often depend on other functions in the package outside the module.  In other words, the `bark()` function in `dog_2.py` might depend on 5 other functions from different modules within the same `animals` package.  At the bottom of each module, I have `if __name__ == '__main__':` because I need to be able to run each module as a stand-alone script but I don't want the module to execute if it is imported into another module.  I could accomplish what I need by adding a bunch of `import` statements to each module to satsify the dependencies, but I thought there must be a better way to do this.

How is this type of problem typically handled?
Essentially, I need to be able to run each module separately as a script, and each module has (possibly) hundreds of dependencies within the same package.

I tried adding to the `__init__.py` a statement: `__all__ = ['dog_1.py', 'cat_3.py', ...]`.  This seems like a good idea.  But the problem I run into is that when I include `from animals import *` at the top of a given module, the import of that current module causes an error.  I thought it was possible to import the module to itself, but for some reason, it is not working.  If I remove the current module from the `__all__` list, then it seems to work fine.
I also tried installing the package locally by creating an outer directory and adding .cfg and setup.py files.  I thought it might fix the problem, but I wasn't able to get anywhere.

I feel like I might be just going about this completely wrongly.  It seems like it would be an easy problem to handle:  Make a bunch of program files in one directory and have them all share the functions between each other.  Any help is appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: Why can't you just use inheritence and classes.

Comment: I thought about using classes, but I didn't see how it would improve things.  The question of figuring out which module to import is now shifted to figuring out which class to inherit.  Maybe you could give me a short example?